# Is windows 7 vulnerable to null session?

Tags: windows, session-management

My lecturer told me that Windows 7 is not vulnerable to null session but did not explain why. What is the preventive measure that windows 7 did to protect against from it?
The recommend fixes for Windows 2000 and XP are to make the following changes:

For Windows 2000:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous=2
```

For Windows XP:
Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts: Enabled (Default)
Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares: Enabled

The same configuration items for Windows 7 are set as:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous=0
```

Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts: Enabled (Default)
Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares: Disabled

Since only one of the three setting changes match I would expect it to still be vulnerable. In that case, why is Windows 7 not vulnerable to null sessions? Any enlightenment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in the day, null sessions were a major issue. The problem with null sessions is the ability to arbitrarily glean usernames from a system, then try password combinations via bruteforce until you manage to log in. Once done, badness ensues - anything you wish to do can be done.

As you can see on your Windows 7 system:

> Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts: Enabled (Default)

Your SAM database (user/password list) cannot be enumerated via a null session, whereas:

> Network Access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares: Disabled

Your Windows shares *can*. This is not the end of the world - without authenticating, all a null session can do is enumerate these shares (unless you've altered your ntfs permissions). That said, if you're feeling paranoid, you can always turn it on. Finally, this switch:

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous=0

Is a bit more complicated. In Windows, there's a group called "Everyone" which with this setting contains the "Anonymous" (unauthenticated) users. This switch basically allows you to share without authentication, which you sometimes want to do.

Switch it to 2, and "anonymous" no longer belongs to "everyone". More [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246261).

Ultimately, null sessions are a problem where they allow enumeration of users and groups without authentication. Beyond this, null sessions (or unauthenticated sharing) becomes a risk depending on whether you're prepared to allow anonymous share enumeration (and use) or not.

So in the classic sense, no, Windows 7 is not vulnerable to null session attacks.

Comment: Thanks dude! You clear all my doubts. Really grateful man!